# calculate fiscal year in sql select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date field that needs to return in fiscal year format. example

```
Start_Date        Year 
04/01/2012 -      2013
01/01/2012 -      2012
09/15/2013 -      2014
```

We need to calculate

```
04/01/2012 to 03/31/2013 is FY 2013
```

and

```
04/01/2013 to 03/31/2014 is FY 2014
```

How can we do that in select statement?

Comment: so you need the end date?

Comment: is your input data correct as per your output in above example ?i think input is wrong .

Answer (score 15):

David has a very good solution.  A simpler expression is:

```
select year(dateadd(month, -3, start_date)) as FiscalYear
```

That is, subtract 3 months and take the year.

EDIT:

As noted in the comment, this seems to produce one year too early.  Here are two solutions:

```
select year(dateadd(month, 9, start_date)) as FiscalYear

select 1 + year(dateadd(month, -3, start_date)) as FiscalYear
```

Comment: I think that's simpler expression than the CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE, but in this particular example you want to add 9 month. If you add 9 months, April will gets bumped up to next year's January.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DatePart(Month, Start_Date) >= 4
            THEN DatePart(Year, Start_Date) + 1
            ELSE DatePart(Year, Start_Date)
       END AS Fiscal_Year
FROM data
```

Comment: A bit code-golfy, but you lose a character of code if you make your first group < 4, and put the +1 under ELSE. And YEAR([date]) is shorthand for DatePart(Year,[date])

Answer (score 1):

I just chose to do it this way. It's easy and you can replace the 09,30 with whatever you want your fiscal year end to be. Not sure if this works in anything but SQL Server though.

```
CASE 
    WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) > 
         SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()),09,30,00,000) 
    THEN 
        DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) + 1 ELSE DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) 
    END AS FY
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Australian** financial year, use the following:

```
SELECT
    year(dateadd(MONTH, 6, DateColumn)) AS FY,
    ...
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a table Fiscal_Year with Start_Date per Year, and you want to find the fiscal year for a given date @Date:

```
SELECT MIN(Year) WHERE @Date >= Start_Date FROM Fiscal_Year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table(StartDate date ,Year1 int)
insert into @t values('04/01/2012',2013),('01/01/2012',2012),('09/15/2013',2014)
;with CTE as
(select max(year1) maxyear from @t)
, cte1 as
 (select cast('04/01/'+convert(varchar(4),a.year1) as  date) FromFY,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(year,1,cast('04/01/'+convert(varchar(4),a.year1) as date))) ToFY


,b.year1 from @t a  inner join (select min(year1)year1 from @t) b on a.year1=b.year1
    union all
   select cast(dateadd(day,1,ToFY) as date),cast(dateadd(year,1,ToFY) as date),year1+1 year1 from     cte1 where year1<=(select maxyear from cte)
)

select * from cte1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME, @ENDDATE DATETIME,@CURR_DATE DATETIME
SET @CURR_DATE='2015-01-30'
IF MONTH(@CURR_DATE) IN (1,2,3)
BEGIN
    SET @STARTDATE= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@CURR_DATE)-1 AS VARCHAR)+'/04/01'  AS DATE)
    SET @ENDDATE= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@CURR_DATE)  AS VARCHAR)+'/03/31'  AS DATE)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @STARTDATE= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@CURR_DATE) AS VARCHAR)+'/04/01'  AS DATE)
    SET @ENDDATE= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@CURR_DATE)+1 AS VARCHAR)+'/03/31'  AS DATE)
END
SELECT @STARTDATE AS ST_FI,@ENDDATE AS END_FY
```

Answer (score 0):

...something simple :)

(YEAR(DATEADD(Month,-((DATEPART(Month,[Date])+5) %12),[Date]))+) AS Financial_Year

Comment: As `-((DATEPART(Month,[Date])+5) %12)` will yield 0 for any [Date] whose month is < 7, and -1 for all others, this function looks like it's supposed to return the year of the current date, or of one month earlier if the date is in the second half of the year. Which will always return the same thing as `YEAR([Date])` Assuming the '+)' at the end was just a typo...

Did you mean `(YEAR(DATEADD(Year,((DATEPART(Month,[Date])+5) %12),[Date]))` - adding a year if five months ahead is in or after december? 

Worth noting the question was looking for a FY starting in April, too...

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Date smalldatetime, @FiscalYearStartMonth tinyint
set @Date = GETDATE();
set @FiscalYearStartMonth = 1; -- Jan

print convert(varchar(4), 
case when MONTH(@Date) < @FiscalYearStartMonth 
then YEAR(@Date) -1 
else YEAR(@Date) end)
```

assuming @Date is your [Start_Date] field, you can:

```
select * from yourTable 
group by convert(varchar(4), 
case when MONTH([Start_Date]) < @FiscalYearStartMonth 
then YEAR([Start_Date]) -1 
else YEAR([Start_Date]) end)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what would look like in oracle to get current financial year. Enter the date for which you want to find fiscal year in place of sysdate

```
 SELECT '01-APR-'
 ||TO_CHAR((add_months(**sysdate**,-3)),'YYYY') FIN_YEAR_START_DATE,
 '31-MAR-'
 ||(TO_CHAR((add_months(**sysdate**,-3)),'YYYY')+1) FIN_YEAR_END_DATE
 FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

For only year format (FY 2020) use following query:

```
SELECT tender_opening_date,CASE WHEN MONTH( order_date) >= 4
            THEN CONCAT('FY ',YEAR(( order_date)) +1  )
            ELSE CONCAT('FY ',YEAR( order_date)-1   )
       END AS Fiscal_Year
FROM orders_tbl
```

For full financial  Year (FY 2019-20) use following query:

```
SELECT tender_opening_date,CASE WHEN MONTH( order_date) >= 4
                THEN CONCAT('FY ',YEAR( order_date),'-',DATE_FORMAT( order_date,'%y') +1  )
                ELSE CONCAT('FY ',YEAR( order_date)-1,'-',DATE_FORMAT( order_date,'%y')   )
           END AS Fiscal_Year
    FROM orders_tbl
```