# Alternative ways to get records between a time frame in SQL (calculate fiscal year)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format, sql-date-functions

I have this table, i wrote, create table query and sample is also data below:

```
DECLARE @TCS_DIVIDEND_PER_YEAR TABLE
(RECORD_DATE DATE,
DIVIDENDPERSHARE INT)

INSERT INTO @TCS_DIVIDEND_PER_YEAR values
('07/16/20',5)
,('06/03/20', 6)
,('03/19/20', 12)
,('01/23/20', 5)
,('10/17/19', 5)
,('10/17/19', 40)
,('07/16/19', 5)
,('06/04/19', 18)
,('01/17/19', 4)
,('10/23/18', 4)
,('07/17/18', 4)
,('05/31/18', 29)
,('01/22/18', 7)
,('10/25/17', 7)
,('07/24/17', 7)
,('06/13/17', 27.5)
,('01/23/17', 6.5)
,('10/24/16', 6.5)
,('07/25/16', 6.5)
,('06/06/16', 27)
,('01/21/16', 5.5)
,('10/23/15', 5.5)
,('07/20/15', 5.5)
,('06/05/15', 24)
,('01/27/15', 5)
,('10/29/14', 5)
,('07/28/14', 5)
,('07/28/14', 40)
,('06/06/14', 20)
,('01/27/14', 4)
,('10/25/13', 4)
,('07/29/13', 4)
,('06/06/13', 13)
,('01/23/13', 3)
,('10/31/12', 3)
,('07/23/12', 3)
,('06/07/12', 8)
,('06/07/12', 8)
,('01/25/12', 3)
,('10/25/11', 3)
,('07/28/11', 3)
,('06/08/11', 8)
,('01/27/11', 2)
,('11/01/10', 2)
,('07/29/10', 2)
,('06/15/10', 4)
,('06/15/10', 10)
,('01/27/10', 2)
,('10/28/09', 2)
,('07/27/09', 2)
,('06/16/09', 5)
,('01/28/09', 3)
,('10/29/08', 3)
,('07/31/08', 3)
,('06/18/08', 5)
,('01/23/08', 3)
,('10/22/07', 3)
,('07/27/07', 3)
```

I would like to get `sum(DIVIDENDPERSHARE)` **between each financial year i.e., 31 March and April 1st** for all the records

For example Dividend sum for 2007 financial year between 31 March 2007 and 1 April 2008 will be 9, this should get iterated for all the records.

Following code is indeed working :

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE
SET @STARTDATE = '04/01/2007'
SET @ENDDATE = '03/31/2008'

WHILE YEAR(@ENDDATE) <= YEAR(GETDATE())
BEGIN   
    SELECT SUM(DIVIDENDPERSHARE) AS DIVIDEND, @STARTDATE AS STARTING_DATE, @ENDDATE AS ENDING_DATE FROM
    @TCS_DIVIDEND_PER_YEAR 
    WHERE RECORD_DATE BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE

    Set @STARTDATE = DATEADD(YYYY,1, @STARTDATE)
    SET @ENDDATE = DATEADD(YYYY, 1, @ENDDATE)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BREAK;
END
```

The output is

```
(58 rows affected)
DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
9           2007-04-01    2008-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
14          2008-04-01    2009-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
11          2009-04-01    2010-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
20          2010-04-01    2011-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
17          2011-04-01    2012-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
25          2012-04-01    2013-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
25          2013-04-01    2014-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
75          2014-04-01    2015-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
39          2015-04-01    2016-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
45          2016-04-01    2017-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
48          2017-04-01    2018-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
41          2018-04-01    2019-03-31

(1 row affected)

DIVIDEND    STARTING_DATE ENDING_DATE
----------- ------------- -----------
85          2019-04-01    2020-03-31

(1 row affected)
```

Are there alternative ways to do it with out using additional tables like calendar tables and with the given information, if so please share I would like to learn

Comment: You want to use `GROUP BY` here, not an iterative process; you're writing SQL not C#. Joining to your calendar table would the the simplest way, as you can then just group on the financial year.

Comment: Does this answer your question [calculate fiscal year in sql select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20554611/2029983)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need a calendar table for this.  If the fiscal year starts on April 1, you can just subtract 3 months and extract the year:

```
SELECT v.FiscalYear, SUM(dpy.DIVIDENDPERSHARE),
       DATEFROMPARTS(v.FiscalYear, 4, 1) as StartFiscalYear,
       DATEFROMPARTS(v.FiscalYear, 3, 31) as EndFiscalYear
FROM TCS_DIVIDEND_PER_YEAR dpy CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dpy.RECORD_DATE)))) v(FiscalYear)
GROUP BY v.fiscalYear;
```

This should be much faster than using a calendar table.

Comment: This query is indeed less work, but when you use a calendar table it will be easier to use an index for better performance.

Comment: @Gert-JanM . . . In this case, a calendar table would multiply out the number of rows by a considerable multiple -- there are only a handful of dividends per year.  The additional data included would be a BIG drag on performance.  I would expect this version to work much, much faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This gives the below error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 71
Incorrect syntax near 'v' at v(FiscalYear) part. Where is this getting wrong

Comment: @Sree . . . There was a missing closing paren.  The current version works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84dddd70277faecad849cced6960fc3d.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar table if you don't have one already.  Make sure it has fiscal year as one of the columns.  Then this can be solved with a very simple query:

```
SELECT ct.FiscalYear,sum(div.DIVIDENDPERSHARE),min(ct.FullDate) as StartFiscalYear,max(ct.FullDate) as EndFiscalYear
FROM CalendarTable ct
LEFT JOIN TCS_DIVIDEND_PER_YEAR div
ON ct.FullDate = div.RECORD_DATE
GROUP BY ct.fiscalYear
```